# How would I make Raspberry Pi send an email with attached picture in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I am a new programmer that has begun learning code on python on raspberry pi 4 4gb. I am currently trying to get the Pi to send me an email that has an attached image. The code currently sends the text but will not send the file. I have attached the code that will send the email. Line 8 has my password for the email in the actual code, but I have replaced that for my accounts security. This code was written in python 3.7.3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'APResearch.test@gmail.com'
email_password = 'passsword goes here'
email_send = 'APResearch.test@gmail.com'

subject = 'subject'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Hi there, sending this email from Python!'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename= '/home/pi/Desktop/intruder.jpg'
attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('APResearch.test@gmail.com','apresearch1')


server.sendmail('APResearch.test@gmail.com','APResearch.test@gmail.com','motion detected')
server.quit()
```

Comment: Your code is an exact copy of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/

Did you read the Important Points? "This code is simple to implement. But it will not work if you have enabled 2-step verification on your gmail account. It is required to switch off the 2-step verification first."